# AngularJS :- Calling a function query

Tags: html, angularjs

Building a Shpping Cart using AngularJS .

I had code the code from a user on JSFiddle.

JS:-

```
function CartForm($scope) {
$scope.invoice = {
    items: [{
        qty: 10,
        description: 'item',
        cost: 9.95}]
};

$scope.addItem = function() {
    $scope.invoice.items.push({
        qty: 1,
        description: '',
        cost: 0
    });
},

$scope.removeItem = function(index) {
    $scope.invoice.items.splice(index, 1);
},

$scope.total = function() {
    var total = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.invoice.items, function(item) {
        total += item.qty * item.cost;
    })

    return total;
}
}
```

HTML

```
<h2>Shopping Card Example</h2>
<div ng:controller="CartForm">
<table class="table">
    <tr>

        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng:repeat="item in invoice.items">
        <td><input  type="text" ng:model="item.description"class="input-small"     readonly="readonly"></td>           
        <td><input type="number" ng:model="item.qty" ng:required class="input-mini">    </td>
        <td><input type="number" ng:model="item.cost" ng:required class="input-mini"     readonly="readonly"></td>
        <td>{{item.qty * item.cost | currency}}</td>
        <td>
            [<a href ng:click="removeItem($index)">X</a>]
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href ng:click="addItem()" class="btn btn-small">add item</a></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>Total:</td>
        <td>{{total() | currency}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I want to have the add item outside the table . How do I access the addItem function  outside the outside the above snippet of HTML code.

JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/slav123/75m7e/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is related to scope visibility: you define your cart login in the `CartForm` scope and you want to access that logic from outside that scope.
There are several ways of doing that:

You could always do it the nasty way: pin any *global* funcionalities to the `$rootScope` to make them visible throughout the whole app:

```
function CartForm($scope, $rootScope) { 
   // ...
   $rootScope.addItem = $scope.addItem;
}
```

Or you could try a cleaner way: you should pack your cart functionalities into a shared service that you can inject wherever you need it:

```
app.factory('CartService', function() {
    // some cart logic here

    // return your cart api
    return {
       addItem: function() {/*...*/}
    }
});
```

After you defined yor cart logic as a factory, you can use it anywhere you want by simply injecting it as a dependency:

```
app.controller('MyPageCtrl', function($scope, CartService) {
    $scope.cart = CartService;
});
```

and use the functionality into the view:

```
<a href ng:click="cart.addItem()" class="btn btn-small">add item</a>
```

Comment: I dont understand what he wants. to move the element outside the table ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir hey i want it outside the DIV (<div ng:controller="CartForm">)

Comment: @user3398752 so put it outside the div , and add a wrapper div which will host the controller scope.

Comment: @user3398752 becuase he messes with the rootScope

Comment: @user3398752 `$rootScope` is like the `window` object for angular. You shouldn't pollute it with all your crap. Instead, you should be more organized in order to make reusable components.

Comment: @gion_13 wll i know i might be asking too much of you . but i am kinda stuck with the shared sevices method. is it possible to edit the JSFiddle ? http://jsfiddle.net/slav123/75m7e/ I would be grateful to you if you do.

Comment: I'm not a fan of coding for other people, but I want to encourage high quality coding, so here's a start for you: http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/LgLFh/ .